# How to download a file from server in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a Node.js backend that sends an icon image to a React frontend. Initially, I encode this image as a Base64 string and store it directly in the database. I created an api that returns this string to the frontend. However, I read that it is bad to store it in the database, so I re-wrote the api to store this string in the server as a json file and now my api returns the absolute path to this json file. However, how is the React frontend supposed to retrieve the file? Is it possible to use the absolute path or do I have to create another api to return a file object ? If so, how do I do that?

I'm a newbie at both react and node.js so any help is appreciated.Thanks.

EDIT: I stored the file path as __dirname of where my code resides + filename.I'm getting cors error when accessing that url

Comment: You can `fetch()` any public url, as long as you stored the file somewhere where the server serves it you can `fetch()` it

Comment: I'm not sure what does public url mean?I just stored the path as the directory name+ filename?

Comment: is the directory served publicly?

Comment: My backend files are uploaded in Plesk....not sure if that means its served publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Express to share out that folder as such-and-such.

Suppose you keep your files in a folder called `files`, just off the root. And suppose your server structure looks roughly like this:

```
- backend
   - app.js
- frontend
   - Components
   - Routes
- public
   - dev
      - index.html  (your template file)
   - files
       - myimage.png
```

In your root js file (app.js? server.js? index.js?):

```
const app = express()
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use('/files', express.static('public/files'));
```

Then, in the frontend code:

```
<img src='/files/myimage.png' />
```

By the way, there is no problem storing images as base64 in your database... but every database backup will also backup those images. If you have a small database, no worries. However, if you have a LOT of images, especially very large images, this will make your database (and backups) unnecessarily large and unwieldy.

Everything depends on your use case.

Comment: Do I have to store the files folder in the public folder?Not sure what this line means...app.use('/static', express.static('public'));

Comment: Geesh, I'm sorry... I left out the `files` folder in the folder tree/map. Answer edited. But yes, that is where you would store the image files you want.  Note that the above tree structure is just an example - I wanted the concept to be clear, so I created a separate folder for the files.

Comment: I tested it locally and it works if i call it using  http://localhost:3000/{folder name}/{filename}. However, I tried it using the application url and it returns 403 error?

Comment: 403 means "not allowed" (permissions error). Is there a login system? Are you authorized? Is it cross-domain? (That is, are you trying to run code on another domain *or subdomain*? Google: CORS) Is the endpoint a web-based api? It's your auth key - check for typos. The server is telling you that you are not authorized for access. I just noticed your comment that you are using Plesk. Sounds like a login issue. Read up on React sessions, creating a login system. ***Mark this ques complete and, if needed, ask a new ques*** *(you will have dozens of ppl reading the new one, not just me).*

Comment: Turns out I had a problem with the file path as local file path is specified using  forward slash \\ and server uses backward slash //